# getting file in while loop by his name

Tags: c#, arrays, image, list, uri

I have a while loop:

```
int a = 0;

while (list_Level[a] < Initial_Lvl)
{
    var dOpt = new DataGridObjectOpt();
    dOpt.ImageSource = new Uri(filePaths[a], UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

    a++;
}
```

In that way i get images from the folder of `filePaths` but i have no control on the order of them unless i change their names.

I want to have the next while loop for example: ( I have 3 images named "apple.jpg","orange.jpg","banana.jpg")

```
int a = 0;
string[] name = ['apple','orange','banana']
while (a < 2)
{
    var dOpt = new DataGridObjectOpt();
    dOpt.ImageSource = new Uri(string.Format("{0}.jpg", name[a]); UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

    a++;
}
```

But still i want it to search for those images in the filepath like before.

Thank You.

Comment: What? What is `LOpt_Temp`? It seems to have nothing at all to do with the rest of the code you've posted. Also, your second snippet has several problems that would prevent it from compiling. I cannot figure out what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have few lists which eventually i ItemSource them into a dataGrid. One of the lists which will be a column in the dataGrid is made of images. i want to concentrate only on this column in my question so i posted it.

Answer (score 0):

Your have to initialize your string array with strings, which are defined in double-quotes, and you need to replace those square brackets with curly brackets:

```
string[] name = {"apple", "orange", "banana"};
```

You also need to replace the semi-colon in the `ImageSource` assignment with a comma:

```
dOpt.ImageSource = new Uri(string.Format("{0}.jpg", name[a]), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

Finally, you are declaring your `DataGridObjectOpt` objects inside your `while` statements, so they only exist while you're inside the loop, which means that your code isn't really doing anything.

It also makes it nearly impossible to give you an answer when we can't tell what you're really trying to do. What is your plan for these `dOpt` objects???

Here's my best guess at a solution for you. It creates a list of `Uri` objects from the `filePath` and the `name` lists you have defined. Then you can later use this for assigning your `DataGridObjectOpt` object `ImageSource` property:

```
var imageSourceUris = new List<Uri>();

for (int i = 0; i < Initial_Lvl; i++)
{
    imageSourceUris.Add(new Uri(filePaths[i], UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
}

string[] names = {"apple", "orange", "banana"};

foreach (var name in names)
{
    imageSourceUris.Add(new Uri($"{name}.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
}

// Now you have a list of Uris that you can assign to
// different DataGridObjectOpt object ListSource properties
// This example just creates a bunch of them and assigns the property

var dataGridOptions = new List<DataGridObjectOpt>();

foreach (var imageSourceUri in imageSourceUris)
{
    dataGridOptions.Add(new DataGridObjectOpt {ImageSource = imageSourceUri});
}
```